# numeric field accepting character in cics map

Tags: cics

can anyone suggest me how to do numeric data processing in cics? i have googled it already but still  my concepts are not cleared. Can Any one share some link or any information related to the topic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on the numeric attribute of a field in a BMS map to restrict input to just numeric digits...

> **Numeric-only** 
>   The effect of this designation depends on the keyboard type of the terminal. On a data entry keyboard, a numeric
>   shift occurs, so that the operator can key numbers without shifting.
>   On keyboards equipped with the “numeric lock” special feature, the
>   keyboard locks if the operator uses any key except one of the digits 0
>   through 9, a period (decimal point), a dash (minus sign) or the DUP
>   key. This prevents the operator from keying alphabetic data into the
>   field, although the receiving program must still inspect the entry to
>   ensure that it is a number of the form it expects. Without the numeric
>   lock feature, numeric-only allows any data into the field.

[...as documented.](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/topics/dfhp3at.html)

You must write code in your program to verify fields contain expected values.